# Change Cell Value based on condition of cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and slowly learning. I cannot seem to find the answer to the following task.

If Cell = Customer1 or Customer3 or customer4, then cell H = Retail

Then I would like to set it up for other customer groups. Is there a way of doing this? I know I can do it one by one. but cannot seem to get it to multiple conditions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use a `Vlookup` table to do that, if I understand your question. Could you add some sample data and a sample output?  Note: You don't likely need VBA, is that okay? Or do you need a solution via VBA?

Comment: Trying to use VBA, to completely automate the task. As of right now I manually do it every morning with a vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic version of the if clause should look like this:

```
Dim value = Range("A1").Value
If value = Customer1 Or value = Customer2 or value = Customer3 Then
    Range("H1").Value = "Retail"
ElseIf value = Customer4 Or/And......
    Range("H1").Value= "Foo"
End If
```

You get multiple conditions with `elseIf`. There is also `Select Case....Case`Example and Info [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php)

Supposing that Customer1/2/3/4 are variables with strings/numbers.

Answer (score 0):

just use formula in the cell you want your answer to be like this:

```
=IF(OR(A1=B1,A1=C1,A1=D1),H1,"Don't Match")
```

assuming your cell to compare is A1 and your customer are B1, C1, D1 and your retail value is H1.